# Code in bash script that changes version of java

Tags: bash

I have to preparae a script that

-switches the current Java to this one: /usr/bin/java

`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME”$PATH” export JAVA_HOME=”/usr/bin/java”`

What should I add to it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/bin/java` is not a directory, but an executable file.

The `JAVA_HOME` should point to Java's installation directory, if at all required. Most of the time, you don't actually need to define `JAVA_HOME` as it's only used by certain applications (such as Maven) to override the version of Java that would otherwise be found on the `PATH`.

So all you need to do is:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

and this will make the `java` command be taken from the `/usr/bin` directory. This is normally in your path anyway, but this line ensures it's at the start.

You may also need to delete any existing definition of the JAVA_HOME variable, as that would override /usr/bin/java when used by tools such as Maven.

Comment: `/usr/bin` will already be on the `PATH` unless you have a seriously broken or very, very specialized system.